# Post ordering not working with custom field

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, order

I am trying to create an Events CPT with a widget, and can't seem to fathom out how to get the ordering done right.  My arguments that I have are:

```
$event_args = array(
  'post_type' => 'event',
  'posts_per_page' => $count,
  'nopaging' => true,
  'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
  'order' => 'DESC',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value',
  'meta_key' => 'wca_events_startdate',
  'meta_value' => date( 'd/m/Y' ),
  'meta_type' => 'DATE'
);
```

`$count` is declared as part of the `$instance` for the widget and as a fixed value for the archive page.

When I comment out the ordering arguments, the loop returns the entries I have published.  When I add them in, it returns no records.  I have a custom field (`wca_events_startdate`), which is a text field, with data stored in a `dd/mm/yyyy` format.  I want to order the posts by this field.  I can't for the life of me seem to find how to achieve this.  I have looked through Google for this information before, and came out with the result above.  Could anyone help?

Also, I will look for this, but will ask it here to hopefully speed up getting the code right: Can you help to have it do only future events are displayed (i.e. Those where the `wca_events_date` date is after today's date)?  That would help me immensely.

Answer (score 1):

It is already solved here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889207/how-to-order-wordpress-posts-by-a-custom-field-date

Just make sure you use 'meta_value_num' for 'orderby' and convert your date values from custom meta's to 'yyyymmdd'.